# Check if URL is exists using PHP

Tags: php

I want to check if an URL exists using PHP.  for eg. If someone enters www.adflkjweoifj123912873.com, I want to check if this domain has a website, or its live on the web.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 5):

Curl: `curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`

See for implementation details http://www.php.net/curl

If you only want to verify it is registered you could do a `gethostbyaddr()`, which doesn't mean the IP is reachable or the site exists.

Comment: cURL surely offers a solution but is also rather slow and may have an impact on the performance of an app :(

Comment: I don't really see an alternative unless you want to do somesort of AJAX on the frontend as the user is filling in the form (assuming this is a form of course)

Comment: A js check is not the way to go when checking user input. If they are willingly giving a false domainname, bypassing a js check is perhaps less trivial but easily done. Curl may be somewhat slower, but more reliable, and one could even opt for a head request instead of a full repsonse.

Answer (score 2):

[checkdnsrr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php)  will be usefull . Searches DNS for host/ip strings.